# Right syntax of CommandArgument of imagebutton

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton

How can I pass more than one argument in ImageButton?

Materially:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnCommand="ButtonDelete_Click" ImageUrl="ForumImages/invalid.gif" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID"+'-'+"USERNAME")%>' />
```

I wonder if the line below is wrong or not? I want to pass: both `ID` and `USERNAME` to `ButtonDelete_Click Event` in the code behind.

```
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID"+'-'+"USERNAME")%>'
```

But when I build this page, it has an error:

> The server tag is not well formed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use like below

```
  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") + ";" +Eval("USERNAME")%>'
```

in code there you will find arguments like below

```
   protected void gridview_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {
  string[] arg = new string[2];
  arg = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');
  Session["ID"] = arg[0];
  Session["USERNAME"] = arg[1];

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID"+"-"+"USERNAME")%>'
```

### Edit 1

```
 CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")+"-"+Eval("USERNAME")%>'
```

Comment: thank you but it has an error  'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ID-USERNAME'.